# reverse a general list using scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to reverse a general list using Scheme. How can I reverse a complex list?

I can make a single list like (A B C D) works using my function, but for some complex list inside another list like (F ((E D) C B) A), the result is just (A ((E D) C B) F). How can I improve it?

```
(define (reverse lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
        (append (reverse (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)))))
```

Any comments will be much appreciated!

Comment: And I am expecting the result to be (A (B C (D E)) F). How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of obtaining the expected result. One is to call `reverse` recursively also on the car of the list that we are reversing, of course taking care of the cases in which we must terminate the recursion:

```
(define (reverse x)
    (cond ((null? x) '())
          ((not (list? x)) x)
          (else (append (reverse (cdr x)) (list (reverse (car x)))))))

(reverse '(F ((E D) C B) A))

'(A (B C (D E)) F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that uses a default parameter `(r null)` instead of the expensive `append` operation -

```
(define (reverse-rec a (r null))
  (if (null? a)
      r
      (reverse-rec (cdr a)
                   (cons (if (list? (car a))
                             (reverse-rec (car a))
                             (car a))
                         r))))

(reverse-rec '(F ((E D) C B) A))
; '(A (B C (D E)) F)
```

Using a higher-order procedure `foldl` allows us to encode the same thing without the extra parameter -

```
(define (reverse-rec a)
  (foldl (lambda (x r)
           (cons (if (list? x) (reverse-rec x) x)
                 r))
         null
         a))

(reverse-rec '(F ((E D) C B) A))
; '(A (B C (D E)) F)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(A ((E D) C B) F)` is the correct result, if your goal is to reverse the input list. There were three elements in the input list, and now the same three elements are present, in reverse order. Since it is correct, I don't suggest you improve its behavior!

If you have some other goal in mind, some sort of deep reversal, you would do well to specify more clearly what result you want, and perhaps a solution will be easier to find then.

Comment: I see your point. But I am expecting the result to be (A (B C (D E)) F).  How can I improve it?